# How to integrate: $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^3+x^2+x+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, fractions

I want to evaluate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^3+x^2+x+1}$. The lecture only provided me with a formula for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \frac{A}{B}$ where $A,B$ are polynomials and $B$ does not have real zeros. Unfortunately, in the given case $B$ has a zero at $z=-1$ and is not even. Is there a straight forward way to solve this in terms of complex analysis?

Comment: If $P(z) = \prod_{k=1}^3 (z-a_k)$ with $a_i \ne a_j$ then $\frac{1}{P(z)} = \sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{b_k}{z-a_k}$

Comment: I suppose noone cares for any complex analysis approaches and everyone wants to post their partial fraction decomposition solutions...

Comment: I really appreciate complex analysis related ways, anything else is not really of any interest to me.

Answer (score 10):

Yes there is , integrate the following function

$$f(z) = \frac{\log(z)}{z^3+z^2+z+1}$$

Around a key-hole contour. Due to the evaluation of the lines on the positive x-axis the $\log$ will cancel. What is remaining is the evaluation of the residues of the three poles.

**More explanation**

we have three poles $\pm i , -1$. Integrate around the following contour

[image]

$$\int_{r}^{\varepsilon}\frac{\log|x|}{x^3+x^2+x+1}dx +\int^{r}_{\varepsilon}\frac{\log|x|+2\pi i }{x^3+x^2+x+1}dx+ \int_{\gamma_r}f(z) dz +\int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}}f(z) dz = 2\pi i \left(\mathrm{Res}(f,\pm i)+\mathrm{Res}(f,-1)\right)$$
The evaluation of the residues

$$\mathrm{Res}(f,i) = \frac{\log(i)}{3\cdot i^2+2\cdot i +1}  = \frac{i\pi/2}{2i-2} $$
$$\mathrm{Res}(f,-i) = \frac{\log(-i)}{3\cdot i^2-2\cdot i +1}  = \frac{3i\pi/2}{-2i-2}$$
$$\mathrm{Res}(f,-1) = \frac{\log(-1)}{3-2 +1}  = \frac{\pi i}{2}$$

By summing the residues and taking $r\to \infty  , \varepsilon \to 0$. Note that the complex logarithm is easily bounded hence the integrals on the smaller and bigger circles vanish and we get

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{\log(x)}{x^3+x^2+x+1}dx -\int^ \infty_0 \frac{\log(x)+2\pi i }{x^3+x^2+x+1}dx = -\frac{\pi}{2}i$$

Hence we get

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{\log(x)}{x^3+x^2+x+1}dx = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Lol, I suppose this was intended (from the tags) but somewhat unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, the OP explicitly stated that he wanted a complex analysis approach.

Comment: Yeah, I know, still a tad too complicated for my taste :P

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, might be. But it is a very nice trick to solve complicated integrals.

Comment: Thx, I have never used this particular contour. Gonna check it out, intuitively it makes sense though. :)

Comment: @Marsl, I mad a draw for the contour. Hopefully it is much easier now.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, Look at the edit. Is it that complicated ?

Comment: :P I already saw, and complicated is relative (mainly speaking, relative to the alternatives to this problem)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, Look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2220072/how-to-show-that-int-0-infty-frac-ln-x1x2-mathrm-dx-0/2220109#2220109, I really made it complicated.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x-1}{x^4-1}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x}{1-x^4}\,dx +\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2-x}{x^4-1}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
by just breaking the integration range as $(0,1)\cup (1,+\infty)$ and applying the substitution $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$ on the second "half".

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{x^3+x^2+x+1}=\frac{1}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)$$

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art No, I do not accept your apologies. See the name of the topic. Is there any mistake in my hint?

Comment: There is no mistake.  But in the same manner, this is like saying you should use the sum rule, product rule, and power rule to find the slope of a straight line on an algebra question.  Its not wrong, but it fails to make notice of what the question is asking.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Factor 
$$x^3+x^2+x+1=(x+1)(x^2+1)$$
and use partial fractions decomposition.