# How do I fight loss of significance and/or improve convergence for this recursive algorithm?

Tags: numerical-methods, recursive-algorithms, rounding-error, catastrophic-cancellation

While trying to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2636074/269624) I used the series approach and obtained a recursive algorithm. While checking it numerically, I found it suffering from "catastrophic cancellation", i.e. loss of significant digits, and extremely slow convergence.

> I would like to know if the algorithm can be improved or if I should just give it up as a bad idea (I was going to apply the same approach to other integrals).

---

With some simplifications from the previous answer, the algorithm is as follows:

$$0<k<1$$

$$ \begin{cases} T_0 = \dfrac{k^2}{\sqrt{1-k^2}} \\  P_0=1 \\ S_0=0 \end{cases}$$

$$ \begin{cases} T_n = \dfrac{1} {k^2}  T_{n-1} -P_{n-1}\\ P_n=\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2n} \right)P_{n-1} \\  S_n=S_{n-1}+\dfrac{T_n}{2n-1} \end{cases} \quad,\quad n \geq 1$$

From another answer to the linked question, I know that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n=\frac{k }{2 \sqrt{1-k^2}} \log \left(\frac{1+k}{1-k}\right)$$

But it had been extremely hard to get a good numerical agreement with the closed form, for the reasons stated above.

I understand why the cancellation happens: the expression for $T_n$ at each step contains subtraction of two numbers (apparently) close to each other in value.

---

This is what I get for $k=1/3$ in Mathematica, using $10^5$ steps of the algorithm and keeping $10^5$ digits for numerical evaluation at each step. Setting $10^4$ digits instead for the same number of steps makes the numerical result $0$.

```
In[804]:= Nm=100000;
k=1/3;
S0=0;
P0=1;
T0=k^2/Sqrt[1-k^2];
Do[T1=N[T0/k^2-P0,10^5];
P1=N[(1-1/(2 n)) P0,10^5];
S1=N[S0+T1/(2 n-1),10^2];
T0=T1;
P0=P1;
S0=S1,{n,1,Nm}];
N[S0,20]
N[(k Log[(1+k)/(1-k)])/(2 Sqrt[1-k^2]),20]
Out[810]= 0.12230925274427951206
Out[811]= 0.12253226793356839896
```

---

Note: I do not want closed forms for $T_n$ or $P_n$, I know them. I would like to know if the algorithm itself can be improved, without getting to the closed forms and then setting up some different algorithm based on them.

Comment: To my understanding, you're using this algorithm to numerically evaluate an integral. There exist standard ways to do it (which is robust) instead of calculating the series you derived... Anyhow, to accelerate convergence, you may want to check the standard methods, e.g. Aitken method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration

Comment: @JiaqiLi, thank you, but I'm interested in improving specifically this algorithm, not using something else to evaluate the integral (which has a closed form anyway). As for series acceleration, the problem is not precisely the slow convergence of the series, the problem is the cancellation when computing the terms

Comment: Is this recurrence relation transcribed wrong? I can't seem to get this to converge like you do. $T_n$ gets very large because you're multiplying by 9 on each iteration.

Comment: @law-of-fives, it seems to work (approximately) as written here (and the code) for any value of $k$ I tried. I just checked it again by copying in Mathematica and the code works. As for $9$, I also used large imaginary values of $k$, the convergence was just as bad